# How to extract data with Goutte Crawler?

Tags: php, goutte, domcrawler

This code, returned  hrefs to content,  now I want to extract content form this hrefs and sent it to my view. Name divs which I need to extract:

```
<div class="c_pad">
  <div class="c_label">
    <span class="std_header2">Contact:</span>
  </div>
<div class="c_name">
  <span class="std_text_b">Monkey</span>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div class="c_pad">
    <div class="c_label">
      <span class="std_header2">Phone number:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="c_phone">
      <span class="std_text_b">001111111</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
for($i=0; $i <= 1; $i++)
    {
      $p = new Client();
      $d = $p->request('GET', ''.$link.'&std=1&results='. $i);
      $n = $d->filter('a[class="o_title"]')->each(function ($node) 
        { 
         $pp = new Client();
         $dd = $pp->request('GET', $node->attr('href'));
         $kk = $dd->filter('div[id="adv_desc"]')->each(function ($tekst) {  echo $node->attr('href').'<br>'.$tekst->text(); 
                    });
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to filter specific tags with attributes.

But you are using `$d->filter('a[class="o_title"]')`.
This filters the tag `a` with the attribute `class="o_title"`. And that's not part of your content.

You simply need to adjust your node filter to select the correct elements.

Use the jQuery Selectors Syntax: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Referencing the documentation of Symfony's DomCrawler, which is used by Goutte:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-filtering

Comment: edited first post.. but now: `Undefined variable: node`

Comment: You are working on something, where nobody can help you, because we are not able to reproduce the issue. For example: Where in your example is a `div` with `id=adv_desc`? Why `each(function ($tekst)`?  Output the variable $node to check the content. var_dump() is your friend.